# Running stored procedure in vb.net results in "invalid column name"

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, stored-procedures, parameters

I am trying to execute a stored procedure with parameters in a vb.net application, and keep getting an error

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Invalid column name 'r'

I tried to find a solution but a lot of the questions seemed to be around inserting data, whereas I am only trying to read data.

I'm simply not sure where it is picking up that I am trying to reference 'r' as a column name? The results are exported to a DataGrid box on the form.

Code:

```
Private Function GetResults() As DataTable
    Dim dtAccounts As New DataTable
    Dim connString As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("PBSQL").ConnectionString
    Dim CountDoc As String = "rqs.service_id,svc.service_abbrev,do.doctor_id,do.dr_first_name,do.dr_surname"
    Dim NoCountDoc As String = "rqs.service_id,svc.service_abbrev"

    Using conn As New SqlConnection(connString)
        Using cmd As New SqlCommand("EXEC dbo.aslGetCommonv1 @StartDate, @EndDate, @GroupBy", conn)

            cmd.Parameters.Add("@StartDate", SqlDbType.Date).Value = dateFrom.Value
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@EndDate", SqlDbType.Date).Value = dateTo.Value

            If cb_SearchByDoc.Checked = True Then
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@GroupBy", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = CountDoc
            Else
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@GroupBy", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = NoCountDoc
            End If

            conn.Open()

            Dim reader As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
            dtAccounts.Load(reader)

        End Using
    End Using

Process:
    Return dtAccounts

End Function

Private Sub BtnSearch_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSearch.Click
    dgResults.DataSource = GetResults()
End Sub
```

Here is the procedure in SQL:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[aslGetCommonv1]
    @StartDate varchar,
    @EndDate varchar,
    @GroupBy varchar
AS
    DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(MAX)
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SET @SQL = 'SELECT rqs.service_id,svc.service_abbrev,do.doctor_id,do.dr_first_name,do.dr_surname,
    COUNT(*) AS total
    FROM dbo.requests_services rqs
    LEFT JOIN services svc ON svc.service_id = rqs.service_id
    LEFT JOIN requests rq ON rq.request_id = rqs.request_id
    LEFT JOIN doctors do ON do.doctor_id  = rq.doctor_id
    WHERE rq.entry_date BETWEEN ' + @StartDate + ' AND ' + @EndDate + ' AND svc.service_id BETWEEN 1005 And 1008 Or svc.service_id = 1401 Or svc.service_id = 1402 Or svc.service_id = 1404 Or svc.service_id = 1405
        OR svc.service_id = 1407 OR svc.service_id = 1408 OR svc.service_id = 1410 OR svc.service_id = 1501 OR svc.service_id BETWEEN 1503 AND 1506 OR svc.service_id = 1509
        OR svc.service_id BETWEEN 5101 AND 5103 OR svc.service_abbrev = ''SADREN'' OR svc.service_abbrev = ''SADREN2'' OR svc.service_abbrev = ''SFH28'' OR svc.service_abbrev = ''SLPSAL''
        OR svc.service_abbrev = ''TFT'' OR svc.service_abbrev = ''CTA'' OR svc.service_abbrev = ''VITD'' OR svc.service_abbrev = ''U216 OH'' OR svc.service_abbrev = ''U2416 OH''
        OR svc.service_abbrev = ''UEMET'' OR svc.service_abbrev = ''CALP'' OR svc.service_abbrev = ''FAEPCR'' OR svc.service_abbrev = ''CDSA1'' OR svc.service_abbrev = ''CDSA2'' 
        OR svc.service_abbrev = ''CDSA3'' OR svc.service_abbrev = ''CDSA3+'' OR svc.service_abbrev = ''CDSA4'' OR svc.service_abbrev = ''CDSA4+'' OR svc.service_abbrev = ''CDSA5''
        OR svc.service_abbrev = ''INTPERM'' OR svc.service_abbrev = ''SIBO2'' OR svc.service_abbrev = ''SIBO3'' OR svc.service_abbrev = ''GIEFFCO'' OR svc.service_abbrev = ''GIEFFME'' OR svc.service_abbrev = ''CMAP''
        OR svc.service_abbrev = ''CMMR'' OR svc.service_abbrev = ''IGA96'' OR svc.service_abbrev = ''IGA96AS'' OR svc.service_abbrev = ''IGG144'' OR svc.service_abbrev = ''IGA144'' OR svc.service_abbrev = ''IGG208''
        OR svc.service_abbrev = ''IGA208'' OR svc.service_abbrev = ''IGG+A208'' OR svc.service_abbrev = ''ALC050'' OR svc.service_abbrev = ''ALC100'' OR svc.service_abbrev = ''ALC150'' OR svc.service_abbrev = ''ALC200''
        OR svc.service_abbrev = ''ALCPLAT'' OR svc.service_abbrev = ''CYTOK'' OR svc.service_abbrev = ''HIAM'' OR svc.service_abbrev = ''DAO'' OR svc.service_abbrev = ''KRPR'' OR svc.service_abbrev = ''ENEUM'' OR svc.service_abbrev = ''LIPOSCRN''
        OR svc.service_abbrev = ''INEUM'' OR svc.service_abbrev = ''ANEUM'' OR svc.service_abbrev = ''ORGANIX'' OR svc.service_abbrev = ''UIODL'' OR svc.service_abbrev = ''MTHFR'' OR svc.service_abbrev = ''OM3INPR''
        OR svc.service_abbrev = ''ONCOSTAT'' OR svc.service_abbrev = ''ONCONEXT'' OR svc.service_abbrev = ''ONCONPLUS'' OR svc.service_abbrev = ''ONCOTRACE'' OR svc.service_abbrev = ''ONCOTRAIL'' OR svc.service_abbrev = ''ONCOCOUNT''
        OR svc.service_abbrev = ''IMMUNOSTAT'' OR svc.service_abbrev = ''NAGALASE'' OR svc.service_abbrev = ''PRIMESPOT'' OR svc.service_abbrev = ''CHEMOSNIP''
    GROUP BY ' + ' ' + @GroupBy + '
    ORDER BY rqs.service_id ASC'

    EXEC(@SQL)
```

Comment: Why is the `GROUP BY` dynamic, when the `SELECT` is not? Does this even need dynamic SQL?

Comment: Most of your left joins are logically inner joins. That long list of "OR" comparisions - just turn it into the equivalent IN construct to make your code easier to read and easier to maintain. Your attempt to dynamically change the grouping won't work. That count looks very suspicious. Please - get help.

Comment: @Larnu - I'm embarassed that I hadn't picked up on that, the Group By does need to be dynamic and as such so does the Select, so I need to change that.

Comment: @SMor I had looked at the IN function but couldn't quite make sense of it. I did try it again today however and got it nailed. Thanks for your input :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you've defined your stored procedure parameters as just `varchar` - without specifying a length.

This does **NOT** specify a `varchar` of whatever length is needed - the default length is **1 character** - so if you pass in any string that starts with an `R........`, it will be **truncated** to just `R` .....

So the **strong** recommendation is: **ALWAYS** define an **explicit length** for your `varchar` parameters and/or variables in T-SQL!

And also: if you pass in dates - the recommendation is to use the most appropriate datatype - not `varchar` in this case, but rather `DATE` or `DATETIME2(n)` .....

So try this :

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[aslGetCommonv1]
    @StartDate DATE,
    @EndDate DATE,
    @GroupBy VARCHAR(100)
```

and I would also strongly recommend to define that length in the VB.NET code where you call this stored procedure:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@GroupBy", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = CountDoc
                                                ^^^^^^
```

Comment: You'll need to explain to the OP how to parametrise dynamic SQL here too and safely inject values. They have a major security convetn right now.

Comment: Whoops; Concern*

Comment: "the default length is 1 character - so if you pass in any string that starts with an R........, it will be truncated to just R ....." This is just not true! Yes it is preferable to include the field size but there will only be data loss for strings longer than field size in the database.

Comment: @Mary: it's **absolutely** true - just try it yourself! Very simple and easy....

Comment: @Mary - if you don't believe me - just try this: `create procedure dbo.TestEcho (@In VARCHAR) as begin select @in,  len(@in); end; `  and then call it with `exec dbo.TestEcho @In = 'Richard the Third'` and the output is nothing more than  `R | 1` .....

Comment: @marc_s Very sorry. I didn't read carefully and thought you were referring to Parameters.Add method. Skipping the field size there can have undesirable results but not truncation. I am an advocate of the .Add method over .AddWithValue so I have a narrow view. I am always adding parameters in vb code but only occasionally write stored procedures. Sorry again.

Comment: Thanks @marc_s! That was exactly what the issue was. I'm sure this was not the case last time I did something like this (probably a good 10 years ago) but I'm clearly wrong. Now to work out the bugs in my stored procedure...

Comment: @Mary: agreed - I also favor the `.Add()` over `.AddWithValue`, and in this case with the `.Add` method, in fact, leaving out the varchar length is not causing the problems I described. It's still a good practice to provide it for clarity - but it's not as harmful to leave it out as it is if you do so in the actual SQL code